# Strok spaces using buffer/dynamic memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, strtok

how could I strtok at spaces while reading in data from a buffer? If my text file contained

1 23 50

45 50 30

2 15 30

and I decide to print the array with my code below, it will print line by line. How could I extend this to further divide the array into individual numbers for each index of the array? Eg.

1

23

50, etc...

I've tried playing around with strtok but I keep segfaulting and I wasn't sure where to fix it.

```
FILE * fp;
char buffer[5000];
int size = 0;
char **entireFile = NULL;
fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

entireFile = malloc(sizeof(buffer) * sizeof(char*));

while (fgets(buffer,5000,fp)!= NULL)
{
    entireFile[size] = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
    strcpy(entireFile[size],buffer);         
    size++;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use strtok? This is one of they very few instances where scanf/fscanf will actually work as expected. Is it a 2d 3x3 array you want? Or 1d Array?

Comment: Hmm.. I guess fscanf could work but the only problem is not every line has 3 numbers.. so if I did fscanf("%d %d %d) wouldn't it fail? (The entire input file was larger varying from 1-3 numbers per line)

Comment: You can scan in one integer at a time with fscanf until the end of the file. In your original example you have a 1d array (buffer). How did you plan on storing a 2d array in a 1d array? If you want to divide the array into individual numbers, scanning them in with fscanf will by far be the easiest way.

Comment: I just planned on storing each number at each indivual index. Right now my code stores entireFile[0] =  1 23 50, I want entireFile[0] = 1, entireFile[1] = 23, etc. Ill try fscanf

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes, I worked around with it and used the fscanf concept. Thank you

Comment: If either mine or @Weather Vane 's answers solved your problem, mark them. If not, submit your own and mark it in 24 hrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want entireFile[0] = 1, entireFile[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) = 23

This can easily be accomplished with fscanf. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) is a pretty good reference for scanning in inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *in = fopen("in.txt" , "r");
    int hold;

    /* Won't actually store values, but can be used for
       value manipulation inbetween */

    while ( fscanf(in, "%d", &hold) != EOF ){
        printf("Scanned in %d\n", hold);
    }

    fclose(in);

    return 0;

}
```

If you want this in an array form, add an incrementing integer and change the hold to an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *in = fopen("in.txt" , "r");
    int hold[100], i=0; // Hold a maximum of 100 integers

        while ( fscanf(in, "%d", &hold[i]) != EOF ){
            printf("Scanned in %d\n", hold[i++]);
        }

        fclose(in);

    return 0;

}
```

You could also do dynamic memory allocation like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    FILE *in = fopen("in.txt", "r");

    int i=0, j;
    char* fragments[2000];
    char entry[100];

    while ( fscanf(in, "%s", &entry[i]) != EOF ){
        fragments[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(entry)));
        strcpy(fragments[i], &entry[i]);
        i++;
    }
    for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ ){
        printf("%s\n", fragments[j]);
    }

    fclose(in);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will read 1, 2, or 3 numbers on each line of your file. It uses the return value from `sscanf` to see how many numbers were read from each line. Of course, if there is any rogue non-numerical data, it will mess up.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int a, b, c;
    int res;
    char str [100];
    if ((fp = fopen("file.txt", "rt")) == NULL)
        return 1;

    while(fgets(str, sizeof str, fp) != NULL) {
        res = sscanf(str, "%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
        if (res == 3)
            printf ("3 values %d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
        else if (res == 2)
            printf ("2 values %d %d\n", a, b);
        else if (res == 1)
            printf ("1 value %d\n", a);
        else
            printf ("0 values\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

File content:

```
1 23 50
45 50 30
2 15 30
10 20

100
```

Program output:

```
3 values 1 23 50
3 values 45 50 30
3 values 2 15 30
2 values 10 20
0 values
1 value 100
```